# How can I change background color Entry widget in Monodevelop GTK#?

Tags: monodevelop, gtk#

I'm using *Monodevelop GTK#* and trying change background color in entry widget, but

`entry.ModifyBase(StateType, Gdk.Color)`

or

`entry.ModifyBg(StateType, Gdk.Color)`

don't change background color for me.

Maybe someone faced this problem and solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Many times you cannot actually change anything: Gtk (and hence Gtk#) thinks it knows better than you the best style for you widgets, and that methods do not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify this using the GTK RC files, assuming you are using GTK# v2 and not v3. An RC file declares styles which can be loaded into the windowing engine at runtime, when you start your app.

You can find examples of RC files on the web, however the following is an example of the sort of thing:

```
gtk-color-scheme = "bg_colour:#101010
fg_colour:#FFFFFF
fg_insensitive_colour:#EEEEEE
bg_prelight_colour:#38a4da
bg_selected_colour:#38a4da

gtk-auto-mnemonics              = 1
gtk-primary-button-warps-slider = 1

engine "murrine" 
{
    contrast = 1.0
    glazestyle = 1                  # 0 = flat hilight, 1 = curved hilight, 2 = concave style, 3 = top curved hilight, 4 = beryl hilight
    menubarstyle = 0                # 0 = flat, 1 = glassy, 2 = gradient, 3 = striped
    menubaritemstyle = 1            # 0 = menuitem look, 1 = button look
    menuitemstyle = 0               # 0 = flat, 1 = glassy, 2 = striped
    listviewheaderstyle = 0         # 0 = flat, 1 = glassy, 2 = raised
    listviewstyle = 0               # 0 = nothing, 1 = dotted
    scrollbarstyle = 0              # 0 = nothing, 1 = circles, 2 = handles, 3 = diagonal stripes, 4 = diagonal stripes and handles, 5 = horizontal stripes, 6 = horizontal stripes and handles
    highlight_shade = 0.9555        # set the amount of buttons or widgets hilight
    roundness = 2                   # 0 = squared, 1 = old default, more will increase roundness
    reliefstyle = 2                 # 0 = flat, 1 = inset, 2 = shadow, 3 = gradient shadow, 4 = strong shadow
    lightborderstyle = 1            # 0 = on top, 1 = on all sides
    animation = FALSE               # FALSE = disabled, TRUE = enabled
    gradients = TRUE                
    glow_shade = 1.0
    comboboxstyle = 0               # 1 to colourize below button
    expanderstyle = 0               # 0 = arrows, 1 = circles, 2 = buttons
}

style "entry"
{
    xthickness = 3
    ythickness = 4

    base[ACTIVE] = @bg_colour
    base[INSENSITIVE] = @bg_colour
    base[NORMAL] = @bg_colour
    base[PRELIGHT] = @bg_prelight_colour
    base[SELECTED] = @bg_selected_colour

    bg[ACTIVE] = @bg_colour
    bg[INSENSITIVE] = @bg_colour
    bg[NORMAL] = @bg_colour
    bg[PRELIGHT] = @bg_colour
    bg[SELECTED] = @bg_colour

    fg[ACTIVE] = @fg_colour
    fg[INSENSITIVE] = @fg_insensitive_colour
    fg[NORMAL] = @fg_colour
    fg[PRELIGHT] = @fg_colour
    fg[SELECTED] = @fg_colour

    text[ACTIVE] = @fg_colour
    text[INSENSITIVE] = @fg_insensitive_colour
    text[NORMAL] = @fg_colour
    text[PRELIGHT] = @fg_colour
    text[SELECTED] = @fg_colour
}

class "GtkEntry"                style "entry"
"
```

The C# you need to load your file is as follows, which will need to be called somewhere in your Program static main (). This assumes your GTKRC is an embedded resource inside an assembly in your project:

```
var _a = Assembly.GetAssembly (typeof (<your class>));
using (var _s = _a.GetManifestResourceStream ("<path in class's assembly to GTKRC file>")) {
    using (StreamReader _r = new StreamReader (_s)) {
        string _rc = _r.ReadToEnd ();
        Gtk.Rc.ParseString (_rc);
        Gtk.Settings.Default.ThemeName = "<your theme name>";
    }
}
```